# • How many ”special” words are in $S$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

[image]

My attempt:
the answer of first question is: $$A_{26}^5=\frac{26!}{21!}=26*25*24*23*22=7893600$$
But i got stuck in the second question but i think the answer is $A_{6}^2 A_{20}^3$ is it true ?

Comment: There are $21$ choices for the first letter, $5$ choices for the second, etc. And multiply

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain more ?

Comment: Think about the number of possible choices for each letter, and multiply all of those together

Comment: Please retype contents in words rather than linking an image of words. This helps vision-impaired users and search algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  There are $6$ choices for the second letter, and then $5$ for fourth, giving you $\ A_6^2\ $ for the number of ways those two letters can be chosen.  Independently of that, there are $20$ ways of choosing the first letter, then $19$ of choosing the third and $18$ of choosing the fifth, giving you $\ A_{20}^3\ $ ways of choosing those three letters. Therefore, the total number of ways of choosing the five letters to satisfy the second condition is your answer of $\ A_6^2A_{20}^3\ $.